# Prove that the invariant subspace contains eigenvectors of a real symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, proof-verification, algebraic-graph-theory

There is a lemma which has been stated by Chris Godsil in one of his books as follows

**Let A be an n by n real symmetric matrix. If U is a nonzero A-invariant subspace of $  \mathbb{R} ^{n} $, then U contains a real eigenvector of A.**

To prove this lemma I did the following

Since  $ A $ is a symmetric matrix, then it is orthogonally diagonalizable.
That is,  there exist a $P$ such that $ P^T P =I$ and $ P^T A P = D $ is a diagonal matrix.

Now $P^T$ contains columns which are eigenvectors of $ A $. Let $v_{i}$ be a real eigenvector of $ A $ then it is in $P^T$, and it is nonzero.

Now, let $ B $ be an orthonormal basis of $ U $, then $ u_{i} \in B$ implies  $ Au_{i} \in B$, and also $   u_{i} \cdot  u_{j}=0  $ if $ j \neq i $
Now  $v_{i}$ being  a real eigenvector of $ A $ then it is in $P^T$, and it is nonzero implies that $ Av_{i}=\lambda _{i} v_{i} $ and also  $   v_{i} \cdot  v_{j}=0  $ if $ j \neq i $

**Case 1**:  $   u_{i} \perp  v_{i}  $, then we are done.

**Case 2**:  $   u_{i} \quad  not \quad  \perp v_{i}   $
From  $ Av_{i}=\lambda _{i} v_{i} $ we have  $ (Av_{i})^{T} u_{i} =\lambda _{i} u_{i} \cdot  v_{i} $ which after simplifying yields $ v_{i} \cdot Au_{i} = \lambda _{i} u_{i}\cdot  v_{i} $ 
Thus $ v_{i}  \cdot (Au_{i} -\lambda _{i} u_{i})=0$
This implies that $ Au_{i} -\lambda _{i} u_{i}=0$

This implies that $ u_{i} $ is an eigenvector of $ A $

```
  **My request**
```

Possibly someone might have solved this problem. I want someone to check if the proof that I have used is correct

Comment: which book is this from?

Comment: Algebraic graph theory, chapter 8, the first edition of this guy man@ub2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This lemma is actually the key step in proving that a symmetric real matrix can be diagonalized. If the subspace $U$ is $A$-invariant, then $A$ is a linear mapping from $U$ to itself, and so it can be represented by a matrix $B$ of order $m\times m$, where $m$ is the dimension of $U$. The trick is to show that $B$ is symmetric, and so by induction it has an eigenvector. This will be an eigenvector for $A$.

The difficulty in understanding this argument is that we are representing an $n\times n$ matrix by a $m\times m$ matrix. More precisely we representing the *action* of $A$ on $U$ by an $m\times m$ matrix.